# Capture regex group, edit it and reinsert it in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, markdown, regex-group

How can I use regex to capture groups and manipulate them in Python 3?

Specifically, I would like to extend `.md` (and eventually, any file type) for my team to add an `exec` block e.g.

```sh
>>>sh
echo "Team Report $(date +"%A %")"
>>>
```

I would like to:

- load the file into a string ✅
- capture the groups ✅
- determine the shell flavor from the exec block starting tag e.g. `>>>zsh` == `zsh` ✅
- open a subprocess and execute the contents of the `exec` block in the correct shell flavor with `check_output` ✅

  - replace the `exec` block with the `stdout` of the `check_output` ‍♂️

I can see how to capture the groups with `re` and I can see how to replace the groups with `sub` but I cannot see how to capture the groups, manipulate the group and save it back into it's position

Comment: could be easier to tell people to use a custom language code like `\`\`\`zsh-exec` and get the blocks using a markdown parser.

Comment: You bring up a good point. I don't realllly care about speed too

Comment: However, I would like to support other file types in the future and keep the same `exec` block functionality e.g. `>>>sh echo $(date +"%A %")>>>` in a value for an attribute in a json file

Comment: You can store markdown in JSON strings. If you go with `>>>` you're going to have a problem if you're displaying this markdown anywhere because the markdown formatter won't know how to format it

Comment: actually try using two words `\`\`\`zsh exec`. Atleast GitHub supports adding extra words after the language name and those are just thrown out when formatting https://github.github.com/gfm/#example-113 and you should be able to still get them with whatever Python markdown formatter you use.